# NodeJS Sub-Modules

Tags: node.js, git, npm, module

I've a node application and want to extract some code in sub modules (simple node modules with own dependencies). For now, I don't want separate `git` repositories or `npm registry entries` for that, but just provide them in subdirectories.

One of these modules is named `core`, because it should be used in the main node application as well as in other sub modules.

Let's say this is my structure:

> - myProject
>
>   - package.json
>   - app.js
>   - core
>
>     - index.js
>     - package.json
>   - partner
>
>     - index.js
>     - package.json

partner needs core and `app.js` needs core as well. My approach was to do the following:

```
cd partner
npm install --save ../core
cd ..
npm install --save ./core
npm install --save ./partner
npm install
```

which errored in:

> npm ERR! code ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! errno -2
>
> npm ERR! syscall rename
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/tjorben/dev/myProject/node_modules/.staging/sliced-fc0a1515' -> '/home/tjorben/dev/myProject/core/node_modules/mquery/node_modules/sliced'

My goal ist, that I just have to make an npm install on the base folder (`myProject`) and it installs the dependencies for `core` and `partner` as well. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Just require them instead of installing them as dependencies. `require("../core");` Maybe `npm link` is another option (I don't know much about it, but you can test CLI with that).

Comment: but doesn't that mean I have to `npm install` core and `partner` separately? So, it won't be enough to `npm install` on `myProject`?

Comment: but I'll give `npm link` a shot. Thanks.

Comment: I reread your question and I think I missunderstood you a bit the first time. I posted an answer to clearify on that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have only one `package.json` file for your project meaning only the one in the `myProject` folder. You install all your dependencies for `myProject`, `core` and `partner` into that `package.json`.

You can now require all external dependencies with: `require("depencency");`

It doesn't matter if they are for `core` or `partner` or any other module. You can require them the same way.

If you want to require your own modules just use: `require("./core");`

Remember to use the correct path to the submodule (like `../core` in your `partner` submodule).